# Should I still specify height and width on images when using bootstrap imp-fluid?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I have read that its important to always add a height and width to images, but I'm using bootstraps img-fluid which makes the height and width responsive. So I'm curious on others opinion on this.

I'm currently doing this:

```
<img class="img-fluid"
 src="../images/jurassic-forest-700w.jpg"
 alt="a photo of the walkway at jurassic forest with lush greenery all around and a large brachiosaurus in the distance"
 height= 350px;
 width= 700px;
>
```

Do I need the height and width attributes?

Answer (score 0):

**Bootstrap 4 & 5**:

Since Bootstrap 4, a few new classes regarding images have been introduced.
example:

```
<img src="..." class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
```

What does img-fluid do?

```
.img-fluid {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Images used as thumbnails are `.img-thumbnail`

Images in Bootstrap are made responsive with .img-fluid . max-width: 100%; and height: auto; are applied to the image so that it scales with the parent element.